# Why is my code example not displayed?

Tags: support

I posted my solution for my question [Arquillian with managed Tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23080616) including to listings. But one of it is displayed.

Does someone know why the first listing is not displayed? You can see it if you click on *edit*.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like your code wasn't properly indented. You need 4 spaces for it to be recognised as a code block. Someone has fixed your answer in the meanwhile.

The system thought you were trying to post HTML, and because only a subset of HTML is allowed, your code was not rendered at all.